# Several questions about multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I started recently to learn multiprocessing in python. Regarding this I have some questions. The following code shows my example:

```
import multiprocessing
from time import *

def func(n):
    for i in range(100):
        print(i, "/ 100")
        for j in range(100000):
            a=j*i
            b=j*i/2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Test with multiprosessing
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    t1 = clock()
    pool.map(func, range(10))
    pool.close()
    t2 = clock()
    print(t2-t1)
    #Test without multiprocessing
    func(range(10))
    t3 = clock()
    print(t3-t2)
```

1. Does this code use the four cores of the cpu or did I make a mistake?
2. Why is the runtime without multiprocessing so much faster? Is there a mistake?
3. Why does the `print` command not work while using the multiprocessing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does submit four processes at a time to your process pool. Your multiprocessing example is running `func` ten times, whereas the plain call is running only once. In addition, starting processes has some run time overhead. These probably account for the difference in run times.

I think a simpler example is instructive. `func` now sleeps for five seconds, then prints out its input `n`, along with the time.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def func(n):
    time.sleep(5)
    print([n, time.time()])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Test with multiprosessing
    print("With multiprocessing")
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    pool.map(func, range(5))
    pool.close()

    #Test without multiprocessing
    print("Without multiprocessing")
    func(1)
```

`pool.map(func, range(5))` runs `func(0)`, `func(1)`, ..., `func(4)`.

This outputs

```
With multiprocessing
[2, 1480778015.3355303]
[3, 1480778015.3355303]
[1, 1480778015.3355303]
[0, 1480778015.3355303]
[4, 1480778020.3495753]
Without multiprocessing
[1, 1480778025.3653867]
```

Note that the first four are output at the same time, and not strictly in order. The fifth (`n == 4`), gets output five seconds later, which makes sense since we had a pool of four processes and it could only get started once the first four were done.